# How can I stop maven-compiler-plugin altering version of dependency when building with JBPM libraries?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, jbpm, fasterxml

I have been seeing the warning below for months and key aspects of JBPM are not working with my code so how do I solve:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.10.redhat-00005 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.10.redhat-00005 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.redhat-00005 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Given that I have been specifying the relevant dependencies in my pom.xml as:

```
    <properties>
        <jbpm.version>7.44.0.Final-redhat-00006</jbpm.version>
        <myJackson.version>2.10.0</myJackson.version>   <!-- was 2.9.0 -->          
...
    </properties>
...
                </plugin>
                <!--plugin> <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                     <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                    <version>${jbpm.version}</version> 
                    <extensions>true</extensions> <dependencies> 
                </plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
...
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${myJackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${myJackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${myJackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am hoping that when the Jackson libraries are consistent my projects issues go away.  How should I change my pom.xml to resolve the missing pom files?  Version 2.9.10.redhat-00005 does not exist that I know of and I also don't think they are Redhat's - which would likely be version 00006, not 00005, from the JBPM.

Comment: I don't think Maven is altering anything. When traversing the dependency tree, they find references to non-existent POMs. This need not be a problem. Just have a look at `mvn dependency:list` to see which dependencies are used in your project.

Comment: The question is also why do you use a version of jackson which is not available on central? Why not using the versions of central https://search.maven.org/search?q=com.fasterxml.jackson.core apart from that why using an older version?